# ZF2 Partial ViewHelper

Tags: zend-framework2

Editing the original post to be more clear. Now there is a new area of trouble that I believe is pure syntax.

I'm new to OOP and Zend Framework 2. Trying to understand the use of partials. I'm also extending an application first started by someone else. So the naming convention of the Entity/Gateway/Controller/View ensure that for a specified action, the correct template is returned.

I'm trying to use "partial('/nav/index.phtml');" as a way of inserting one snippet in the header on the index page. But I want to use a different partial on other pages.

Following Marshall's suggestion, in the TemplateController, I am adding a variable (nav_template) to the viewModel specifying which partial to use for the navigation:

```
    <?php

    namespace Application\Controller;

    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

    class TplController extends AbstractActionController
    {
        public function topicAviewAction()
        {
            $viewModel = new ViewModel();
            $viewModel->setTerminal(true);
        $viewModel->setVariable('nav_template', 'nav/topica.phtml');
            return $viewModel;
        }

        public function topicBviewAction()
        {
            $viewModel = new ViewModel();
            $viewModel->setTerminal(true);
        $viewModel->setVariable('nav_template', 'nav/topicb.phtml');
            return $viewModel;
        }
    }
```

I used the below command to verify that my variable was being included in the object, which it was

```
    echo $viewModel->nav_template;
```

However, when I go to include the partial in layout.phtml using the following:

```
    <?php echo $this->partial(isset($nav_template) ? $nav_template : 'nav/index'); ?>
```

It is obviously not using/finding the value of $nav_template. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It's because you are setting the variable to the view script and not the layout. See my answer again and look closely to what the variable is getting assigned to: `$this->layout()->setVariable(`

Comment: Also, you aren't going to get your layout to show up at all if you are using `setTerminal(true)` - which disables layout

Comment: Here is a useful blog post from Rob Allen about accessing viw variables in another view model: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/access-view-variables-in-another-view-model/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the onBootstrap event in your Module class. Make sure to handle it in the route event, otherwise you won't have a routematch yet at that point in onBootstrap. Example:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(
                \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE,
                function($e) {
                    $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
                    $nav = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
                    $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
                    switch ($routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName())
                    {
                        case 'home':
                            $template = 'your/template';
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    $nav->setTemplate($template);
                    $viewModel->addChild($nav, 'nav');
                },
                -1000
        );
        ...
```

In your layout you can then just use: echo $nav;

Please note that you also have to define the templates you use here in your module.config.php in the 'view_manager' => 'template_map' key.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestion Ruben. My first step into ZF2 is extending something first written by someone way more knowledgable. The view manager is specifying the application index, but all the other templates get called through a template controller when the corresponding action is called. So I believe I need to handle this in the controller.

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure I understand the architecture you're describing. Are you saying that all requests are being routed to a template controller that decides what template to use? If so it sounds like a very strange way of handling things.

Comment: The last thing to note in case it throws anyone else is that I had to grab the param values due to the setup of my routing like so:

$routeMatchParams = $routeMatch->getParams();

switch ($routeMatchParams['controller'])
{
    case 'Application\Controller\Topic':

Answer (score 0):

In your layout template, call a dynamic partial with a default fallback like this:

```
<?php echo $this->partial(isset($nav_template) ? $nav_template : 'nav/index'); ?>
```

Then in your controller where you want to change the layout nav:

```
$this->layout()->setVariable('nav_template', 'nav/other');
```

Should work. (untested)

Comment: Ok. I believe this should work, but something is wrong with my syntax.I will update the original post.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, good job, Ruben, but if you use the default routing setup (like from the Skeleton App), it will always return something like `'application\default'` when you use `$routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName()`

Here is a slight mod that will work with regex Segment routes:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(
            \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE,
            function($e) {
                $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
                $nav = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
                $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
                $routeMatchParams = $routeMatch->getParams(); // <-- added this

                switch ($routeMatchParams['controller']) //  // <-- switch on invokable alias of your controller(s)
                {
                    case 'Application\Controller\YourController':
                        $template = 'your/custom-template';
                        break;

                    default:
                        $template = 'your/default-template';
                        break;

                }

                $nav->setTemplate($template);
                $viewModel->addChild($nav, 'nav');
            },
            -1000
    );
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, i think all you need to do is use...

```
$this->nav_template
```

in place of...

```
$nav_template
```

Other frameworks do things differently, but in ZF2 the variables are set to the viewmodel itself, thus can be called from within the layouts/views using the magic getter method and grabbing it from the $data variable within the View/View model class.

Point being...

Use...

```
$this->nav_template
```